# SSAS - Attribute appears empty despite having a value

Tags: excel, ssas

A user mounted a report on Excel based on a cube. But since a unknown moment, it shows me blank data in filters and in table but value really exists.

As you can see in this Picture

[image]

the segment can show me the value (I filtered with the segment).

If I create a new report on cube, it will correctly show the value.

Does anyone know how to fix it or why it can appear ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you start a new workbook and new PivotTable can you reproduce that? It’s possible someone typed over that value when it was on the rows axis and renamed it within your PivotTable

Comment: It is possible. In this case, Is there any way to get data back (like with "Refresh" button for example) ?